# Lambda cannot make POST requests to REDIS Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, redis, fastapi

`Lambda -> FAST API -> REDIS Cloud (Public)`

For the life of me, cannot figure out why my FAST API on Lambda cannot make POST requests to my Redis DB.

My POST Request does:

```
def redisSave(memory):
    memory_data = json.dumps({
    DATASET
    })
    redis_connection.set(
                        DATASET
                        )
    redis_connection.geoadd(name='DATASET',values=[DATASET.lon, DATASET.lat, DATASET.id])
    pass
```

This works normally locally, and can even use Postman to make the POST.

But cannot make the request on Lambda with this error:

```
 Undocumented

TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

======

My Lambda can make GET Requests just fine to the Redis database, so I know it is connecting to the database. But cannot make Any POST requests, any clues?

Comment: Is your Lambda function configured to run within a VPC by any chance?

Comment: It is not, I tried the VPC approach when I was using Elasticache to host my RedisDB, but that was a pain.

End of the day, I ran my API in my EC2 and works just fine

Answer (score 0):

tldr, Dont Do this, something about Lambda Config does not allow it to make a Redis connection.

I ran it via my Ec2 instance and called it a day, works well with a Load Balancer